# Word overflowing in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, southeast-asian-languages

I am working on a khmer site, I dont know the language, the words are too long. I am trying to fit them in div but they are over flowing. Is there a way that the part of word comes down automatically such that it fits in the div, and over flow part is in next line.

I dont know what to do with it, please help.

Find the image in the attachment
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `word-wrap` property of CSS to force the text to stay inside div without overflowing.

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/dsmLq4r2/)**

Check without this property and with it to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works - word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) CSS property:

```
.mydiv {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan pleasure to help. Mark an answer as the correct answer when confirmed please :)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can give the below CSS style to the div to prevent the div text from overflowing.

div {
     word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an CSS Attribute for "text overflow" inside HTML Objects

You can do somesthing like that to prevent an overflow by default.

```
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

[reference at W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Please note that text-overflow property only occurs when the containers overflow property has the value hidden, scroll or auto.

If you want to warp the long words in multiple lines instead of just "cutting" them you may use "word-wrap: break-word;" which causes the Browser to split long words. ([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp))

Please note that both specs are widely supported but very old browsers may ignore them. You can see details in the references.